# Fractions and formats in Excel

Tags: excel, format, fractions

I can convert Decimal to Fractions in Excel.
i.e. 1.25 to 1 1/4
However, I want it to appear in the format 1¼ with the fraction in superscript and subscript format.
Is there a VB code for doing this?
I can create fractions using the formula function, but this is a stand alone text box and not in a referenced cell

Can anyone help and advise?

I don't know what to try!

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky if you have more unusual fractions, 11/15 for example. Whenever you have a value like the one I just gave, Excel will automatically change the cell format to Fraction. This makes it difficult to reduce the font size of the fraction element of the number. It's not impossible, but you'd need to change the cell to Text format which makes the function difficult to reproduce if you change a value.

If you just have fractions that can be managed by your typeface (Calibri, for example, goes as far as eighths, I believe), then you could just use those glyphs. For any others, you'd have to live with the larger numbers in the fraction. Skeleton code would look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private mFractions As Collection

Private Property Get Fractions() As Collection
    Const fracDecPairs As String = _
        "&H00BC|1/4,&H00BD|1/2,&H00BE|3/4," & _
        "&H2153|1/3,&H2154|2/3," & _
        "&H2155|1/5,&H2156|2/5,&H2157|3/5,&H2158|4/5," & _
        "&H2159|1/6,&H215A|5/6," & _
        "&H215B|1/8,&H215C|3/8,&H215D|5/8,&H215E|7/8"
    
    Dim fdps() As String, fdp() As String
    Dim item As Variant
    
    If mFractions Is Nothing Then
        Set mFractions = New Collection
        fdps = Split(fracDecPairs, ",")
        For Each item In fdps
            fdp = Split(item, "|")
            mFractions.Add CLng(fdp(0)), fdp(1)
        Next
    End If
    Set Fractions = mFractions
End Property

Public Function DecToFrac(dec As Double) As String
    Dim txt As String
    Dim num() As String
    Dim frac As String
    
    txt = WorksheetFunction.Text(dec, "# ##?/##?")
    num = Split(txt, " ")
    
    If UBound(num) = Len(" ?/?") Then 'it's an integer with no fraction.
        DecToFrac = num(0)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If UBound(num) = 0 Then 'it's a fraction with no integer.
        On Error Resume Next
        frac = ChrW(Fractions(num(0)))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If frac = "" Then
            DecToFrac = txt
        Else
            DecToFrac = frac
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    frac = ChrW(Fractions(num(1)))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If frac = "" Then
        DecToFrac = txt
    Else
        DecToFrac = num(0) & " " & frac
    End If
End Function
```